# Динамически привести тип

Tags: c#

```
object obj = ....
Type mytype = this.GetType();
var objType = (mytype)obj;
```

Вот так не получается( в object на самом деле находится другой тип переменной, но заранее не известно какой, однако известно что this.GetType() ей всегда соотвествует.

Comment: Допустим даже вы смогли привести переменную к не известному заранее типу. И что вы дальше с ней будете делать? Если тип неизвестен, то и операции неизвестны. Расскажите лучше свою настоящую задачу. Для чего вам это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так не получается, потому что так можно приводить только к типам, известным во время компиляции.

Вам может помочь тип [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd264741.aspx). Однако вы должны знать, какие операции поддерживает объект. Небольшой пример:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic fooValue = Foo(); // тип возвращаемого значения заранее неизвестен
        Console.WriteLine(fooValue.Length); // выводит 5

        dynamic barValue = Bar(); // тип возвращаемого значения заранее неизвестен
        Console.WriteLine(barValue.R); // выводит 255
    }

    private static object Foo()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }

    private static object Bar()
    {
        return Color.White;
    }
}
```

Также вы можете возспользоваться рефлексией и запрашивать/устанавливать нужные поля/свойства/вызывать методы сперва получая ссылку на них с помощью [`Type.GetField()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/53seyfee(v=vs.110).aspx)/[`Type.GetProperty()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.type.getproperty(v=vs.110).aspx)/[`Type.GetMethod()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8zz808e6(v=vs.110).aspx), а затем работая с помощью `FieldInfo`/`PropertyInfo`.`GetValue()`/`SetValue()` и `MethodInfo.Invoke()` (что менее удобно, конечно).

Comment: Да спасибо помогло)
а я до этого побывал 
var c = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(mytype).ConvertFrom(obj);
и даже
var p = Activator.CreateInstance(mytype, obj); 
и хотя сама студия не жаловалась, но при исполнении появлялись ошибки

Comment: Не за что. Можете пометить ответ как правильный.